# Fetch Github Issue informatiom from Issue ID

Tags: php, git, api, github, github-api

I have been looking around the Github API and couldn't find an endpoint which fetches me the issue details from just an Issue ID. The Issue ID(53454563) is different from an Issue number(#1,#2 etc.). Issue ID is the primary key of the Issue table.

From the Github API documentation, the way to fetch issue details is with a GET request to /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number. I'll need the issue number, the owner name and the repo name to fetch the details.

Is there a way to fetch issue details with just the issue Id?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to fetch issue details with just the issue Id?

No, not possible currently. You could do it with a repository ID and issue number, e.g. https://api.github.com/repositories/1725199/issues/1234.

Answer (score 0):

The [GHTorrent project](http://ghtorrent.org) provides a relational table that uses `ID`, which may be easier for you. There is also a [BigQuery table](https://twitter.com/ghtorrent/status/785443366976811008) with the same data, which I find easier to work with.

I'm not sure what has led you to have only the issue id, but by joining `ght.issues` with Github's own [tables on BigQuery](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/06/GitHub-on-BigQuery-analyze-all-the-open-source-code.html), you might solve the problem without the Github API.