# GitHub what causes gaps in issue #Number (404 This is Not...)

Tags: github

github uses the same auto-increment Number for issues/Pull Requests(PR)/discussions.
(it seems that [issue ID is different from issue Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600211/fetch-github-issue-informatiom-from-issue-id))

---

https://github.com/git/git/issues/10 redirects me to
https://github.com/git/git/pull/10

so I'm fine iterating Numbers like this: https://github.com/git/git/issues/Number

I do this and find that some URLS give:
`404 This is not the Web Page you are looking for.`
[image]

for example: https://github.com/git/git/issues/7

---

What could be the causes ?
I know that this isn't because of deletion because after deleting an issue you land on this page:
`This issue has been deleted.`
[image]

---

to look for patterns,
here's a python3 script to get `<issue Number> : <type of Issue Or 404 Or Deleted>`

```
1: pull request
2: issue
3: 404 Not Found
4: discussion
```

you have to set vars in #EDIT THIS

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os 

#EDIT THIS
#how many issues this repo has
lastIssueNumber=67
ownerSlashRepo="mark-wiemer/vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus"
outFileName='github.scraped'
#EDIT THIS

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

f = open(os.path.join(dir_path, outFileName), "a", encoding="utf-8", newline='\n')

for issueNumber in range(1, lastIssueNumber + 1):
    url = f'https://github.com/{ownerSlashRepo}/issues/{issueNumber}'

    r = requests.get(url)

    if r.status_code == 404:
        message = '404 Not Found'
    elif r.history:
        # print("Request was redirected")
        finalUrl = r.url 

        lastSlash=finalUrl.rfind("/")
        secondLastSlash=finalUrl.rfind("/", 0, lastSlash)

        typeOfIssue=finalUrl[secondLastSlash+1:lastSlash]
        # https://github.com/owner/repo/pull/#Number
        if typeOfIssue=='pull':
            message = 'pull request'
        # https://github.com/owner/repo/discussions/#Number
        elif typeOfIssue=='discussions':
            message = 'discussion'
    else:
        # print("Request was not redirected")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        # class of svg trashbin icon
        # if soup.select_one('.octicon.octicon-trash.blankslate-icon'):
        if soup.find("svg", {"class": "octicon octicon-trash blankslate-icon"}):
            message = 'found trash icon'
        else:
            message = 'issue'


    toAppend = f'{issueNumber}: {message}\n'
    print(toAppend, end='', flush=True)
    f.write(toAppend)
    # Ex:
    # 1: pull request
    # 2: issue
    # 3: 404 Not Found
    # 4: discussion

f.close()
```

I've used this on https://github.com/mark-wiemer/vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus and got

```
1: pull request
2: pull request
3: pull request
4: pull request
5: issue
6: pull request
7: pull request
8: pull request
9: issue
10: issue
11: issue
12: pull request
13: pull request
14: discussion
15: pull request
16: issue
17: discussion
18: issue
19: issue
20: 404 Not Found
21: discussion
22: 404 Not Found
23: discussion
24: 404 Not Found
25: issue
26: issue
27: pull request
28: issue
29: issue
30: discussion
31: pull request
32: pull request
33: 404 Not Found
34: discussion
35: pull request
36: 404 Not Found
37: discussion
38: 404 Not Found
39: discussion
40: issue
41: 404 Not Found
42: discussion
43: discussion
44: issue
45: issue
46: discussion
47: pull request
48: issue
49: issue
50: pull request
51: pull request
52: pull request
53: pull request
54: issue
55: issue
56: issue
57: pull request
58: issue
59: issue
60: issue
61: pull request
62: 404 Not Found
63: discussion
64: issue
65: issue
66: discussion
67: discussion
```

I noticed that all but one `404 Not Found` was followed by `discussion`
you can look for these with this regex `404 Not Found.*?\n.*?discussion`

the one exception is `404 Not Found.*?\n.*?issue`

other than that, it seems pretty random, I'd like to know what these `404 Not Found` gaps mean.

---

bonus: is there a way to get the lastIssueNumber(discussion included) of a repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, I've seen that issues and pull requests will 404 if GitHub's filtering system or moderators decide that a PR/issue is spam.

Comment: I was gonna ask wdym by experience? And I remembered that one of my issues suddenly disappeared (and in place was 404). the issue was useful for future references (formatting error), but my wording could easily be considered spam. I couldn't find the issue when I needed later. If it's decided as spam, there's no way to get it back ?